# how can I solve the Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' error

Tags: node.js, next.js

I don't understand this problem, as I am not using the fs module anywhere, I deleted all the node_modules and package.json and package-lock and reinstalled everything and upgraded node, still get the same error

here is my package.json file for the server side.

```
    {
  "name": "todoapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "backend/server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm run dev --prefix frontend",
    "build": "npm run build --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seeder",
    "data:destroy": "node backend/seeder -d"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.14",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "slugify": "^1.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error and stack trace? What you have provided is not enough

Comment: Maybe your using `fs` in your `app.js` try to remove line of code

Answer (score 0):

`fs` is server-side only e.g you can't use it during page rendering.